# Clicking on a link doesn't work but copy-pasting the link into url works

Tags: mongodb, haml

I'm not entirely sure what is going on with this?  Is there a place I should start?  Is it application level, client level, server level?

Note that no one will be able to help because this server is blocked by a firewall.  All the other links work just by clicking, except this one (gives 500 error), but if I copy and paste it exactly into the url address bar then it pumps out exactly what I want.

```
http://<company-server>/aggregate?
  $project[_id]=0&$project[cmts]=1&
  $group[_id][cmts]=$cmts&$group[count][$sum]=1
```

I am using MongoDB as the backend and HAML as the frontend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Fix Link in HAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531656/how-to-fix-link-in-haml)

Comment: Why did you ask the question again?

Comment: What does the network traffic look like for the two different ways? It would seem like there must be something different.

Answer (score 0):

This is system-dependent and made the difference for my servers, since the bundler versions were different on dev and prod.

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

If it asks, choose all.

```
gem install bundler -v 1.2.2
```